# The game of Sevens! Who said what?

Tags: code-golf, game, counting

The game of Sevens is played as follows: `n` players sit in a circle, and start counting up from 1, passing to the left (or from player `A` to player `B`).

When a number `p` that has a `7` in it OR is divisible by `7` is reached, then the player who spoke the number `p-1`, after the next player says `p`, must say `p+1` and the order of people speaking reverses. For example, if player `B` speaks `6`, player `C` says `7`, `B` says `8`, and player `A` says `9`.

**Note:** For those who want to play in real life, if a person forgets a number (or in the version where `sevens` are not said, accidentally says a `seven`), they are eliminated from the circle, but we will omit this detail from this challenge.

The challenge itself is to print which numbers each player should say in a perfect game of Sevens up to an input `m` for an input `n` players.

As an example, where five people, `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, and `E`, are to play till they reach `30`. They play in this manner

```
A: 1 6 8 13    15 19       23    30
B: 2 7*  12    16 18       24
C: 3     11    17*         25
D: 4     10          21*   26 28*
E: 5      9 14*      20 22 27*29
```

where `sevens` are marked with `*`. Note that at `27` and `28`, we're reversing twice, and play continues "as normal" from `D` to `E`.

Please note that the output does not have to be in the above format. I simply printed it that way for some clarity.

**Rules**

- The input is two integers in any order, `m` representing the last number to say, `n` representing the number of players.
- The output can be several arrays or several strings, one for each player. If you use strings, you do not have to use separators (though, if you could add some in your code tests, we would appreciate the readability). If you can actually print them in a circle somehow, that is acceptable as well, and it would be pretty cool too.
- The output does not have to designate which players are which (it's fairly obvious that the first player is the one who says `1`), though if the output isn't sorted for whatever reason, you should make clear which player is speaking which set of numbers. Omitting players who do not say anything is also allowed if you make it clear which players are speaking. I will add some more examples of possible outputs below.
- This is code golf, so the smallest number of bytes wins.

As always, if the problem is unclear, please let me know. Good luck and good golfing!

**Examples**

```
>>> sevens_string(30, 5, " ")
'1 6 8 13 15 19 23 30'
'2 7 12 16 18 24'
'3 11 17 25'
'4 10 21 26 28'
'5 9 14 20 22 27 29'
>>> sevens_string(42, 5)
'16813151923303539'
'27121618243140'
'31117253241'
'410212628333742'
'591420222729343638'
>>> sevens_array(20, 3)
[1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 15, 19]
[2, 5, 9, 12, 16, 18]
[3, 6, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20]
>>> sevens_array(18, 10)
[1, 13, 15]
[2, 12, 16, 18]
[3, 11, 17]
[4, 10]
[5, 9]
[6, 8]
[7]
[]
[]
[14]
```

Comment: I think a more useful output for purposes of visualizing the game play would be a list of players in order of play. (E.g. with 4 players and a max of 15, that'd be `1 2 3 4 1 2 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 4 1`.) I'm not saying that's better or worse in terms of he challenge: just that it'd be more useful in the real world.

Comment: Can we display the result as a matrix and pad with zeroes?

Comment: @Dennis Empty arrays should be kept. The result may be a zero-padded matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Pyth, 38 bytes

```
Jm[)EA,01VQa@JZ=hG=+Z=W|}\7`G!%G7H_H;J
```

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Jm%5B)EA%2C01VQa%40JZ%3DhG%3D%2BZ%3DW%7C%7D%5C7%60G!%25G7H_H%3BJ&input=20%0A3&debug=0) [Test suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Jm%5B)EA%2C01VQa%40JZ%3DhG%3D%2BZ%3DW%7C%7D%5C7%60G!%25G7H_H%3BJ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=30%0A5%0A42%0A5%0A20%0A3&debug=0&input_size=2)

Basically a port of my Python answer; there's probably a better way. Takes as input the number to count up to `n` and the number of players `p` on separate lines, outputs the result as a two-dimensional array.

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 151 bytes

```haskell
s n|elem '7'(show n)||mod n 7==0=(0-)|0<1=id
a=scanl1(+)$map($1)$scanl(.)id$map s[1..]
f m n=mapM_ print[[x+1|x<-[0..m-1],mod(a!!x-1)n==i]|i<-[0..n-1]]
```

```
*Main> f 30 5
[1,6,8,13,15,19,23,30]
[2,7,12,16,18,24]
[3,11,17,25]
[4,10,21,26,28]
[5,9,14,20,22,27,29]
```

Comment: How about `mod n 7<1` instead of `mod n 7==0` and `s<$>[1..]` instead of `map s[1..]`? Also, why not `print[]` instead of `mapM_ print[]`?

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 155 bytes

```
from turtle import*
def f(m,n,i=0,r=20,d=360):
 k=n
 while i<m:i+=1;fd(r);write(i);bk(r);e='7'[:i%7]in str(i);d*=1-2*e;k=~-e*(1-k)%n;r+=(k<1)*15;rt(d/n)
```

Uses turtle graphics to print in a circle such that numbers spoken by the same player are on the same radius. The radius of the circle is increased when the direction is reversed, or when the sequence wraps around the circle, so previous numbers aren't overwritten.

Sample output for `f(22,6)`

[image]

Comment: Ooh, this is clever and pretty. +1 :D

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>103</s> <s>102</s> 101 bytes

```python
def S(n,p):
 P=0;D=N=1;O=['']*p
 while n:O[P%p]+=`N`;D*=1-2*(N%7<1or'7'in`N`);N+=1;P+=D;n-=1
 print O
```

Defines a function `S(n,p)` that takes the number to count to `n` and the number of players `p` and prints the result as an array of strings.

```
>>> S(42,5)
['16813151923303539', '27121618243140', '31117253241', '410212628333742','591420222729343638']
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>91</s> <s>90</s> 87 bytes

```
def f(m,n):a=d=i=0;r=[()]*n;exec"i+=1;r[a%n]+=i,;d^='7'[:i%7]in`i`;a+=1-2*d;"*m;print r
```

Prints a list of tuples. Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/tA8ZaV).

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>27</s> 25 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
D;Æf7e
R’Ç€^\ḤC+\_'R}⁹ḍT€
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=RDvDhmY3ZQpS4oCZw4figqxeXOG4pEMrXF8nUn3igbnhuI1U4oKs&input=&args=MzA+NQ) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=RDvDhmY3ZQpS4oCZw4figqxeXOG4pEMrXF8nUn3igbnhuI1U4oKsCsOnIkfigqxq4oCcwrbCtg&input=&args=MzAsIDQyLCAyMCwgMTQ+NSwgICA1LCAgMywgMTA).

Comment: why is this not-competing

Comment: Because the challenge is from December 2015 and predates the creation of Jelly.

Comment: Oh, thanks for clarification!

Comment: Is that an official rule? I never check the question date against programming language invention date.

Comment: @ThomasWell [Can I ever answer with a language invented after the challenge was posted?](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4870)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I guess I'll rely on the moderation - that someone will leave a comment or delete the answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Dyalog APL, <s>50</s> <s>47</s> 35 bytes

```
{,⌸⍵|+\0,¯1*+\{0=7|⍵×~7∊⍎¨⍕⍵}¨⍳⍺-1}
```

This displays the numbers each player said as a table, where the first column enumerates the players. Rows are padded with **0**s to the same length, and rows without numbers are omitted.

#### Verification

```
      f ← {,⌸⍵|+\0,¯1*+\{0=7|⍵×~7∊⍎¨⍕⍵}¨⍳⍺-1}
      30 f 5
0 1  6  8 13 15 19 23 30
1 2  7 12 16 18 24  0  0
2 3 11 17 25  0  0  0  0
3 4 10 21 26 28  0  0  0
4 5  9 14 20 22 27 29  0
      42 f 5
0 1  6  8 13 15 19 23 30 35 39
1 2  7 12 16 18 24 31 40  0  0
2 3 11 17 25 32 41  0  0  0  0
3 4 10 21 26 28 33 37 42  0  0
4 5  9 14 20 22 27 29 34 36 38
      20 f 3
0 1 4 7 10 13 15 19
1 2 5 9 12 16 18  0
2 3 6 8 11 14 17 20
      14 f 10
0  1 13
1  2 12
2  3 11
3  4 10
4  5  9
5  6  8
6  7  0
9 14  0
```

Note that, in the last example, **7** and **8** are omitted since those players haven't said anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 81

```
->n,m{g=[""]*n
k=j=0
i=1
m.times{g[j%n]+=w="#{k+=1}"
j+=i=k%7<1||w[/7/]?-i :i}
g}
```

Pretty straightforward implementation.  Returns an ugly glommed string (you can add a space to make it `"#{k+=1} "` for... well, a spaced string).  I wonder if there's a more mathematical algorithm out there.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](http://factorcode.org) 172

I managed to do it longer than Haskell, and as readable as APL! Do I get a cookie?

```
[| l! n! | 1 0 0 :> ( p! x! z! ) n iota [ 1vector ] map <circular> n! l iota [ 1 + z! z 7 mod 0 = 55 z 10 >base in? or -1 and 1 or p * p! z x n nth push x p + x! ] each n ]
```

It's a quotation (anonymous function) that outputs a circular sequence of vectors. Each vector starts with the number of player, and then the numbers that correspond to that player.

```
30 5 [| l! n! | 1 0 0 :> ( p! x! z! ) n iota [ 1vector ] map <circular> n! l iota [ 1 + z! z 7 mod 0 = 55 z 10 >base in? or -1 and 1 or p * p! z x n nth push x p + x! ] each n ] call

Outputs:
T{ circular
    { seq
        {
            V{ 0 1 6 8 13 15 19 23 30 }
            V{ 1 2 7 12 16 18 24 }
            V{ 2 3 11 17 25 }
            V{ 3 4 10 21 26 28 }
            V{ 4 5 9 14 20 22 27 29 }
        }      ^ Note: first val is player number starting at 0
    }
}
```

I started with this:

```
: game-of-7 ( last-num num-players -- {players:={numbers}} )
  1 1 set ! increment
  0 2 set ! current-index
  iota [ drop V{ } clone ] map <circular>
  swap iota
  [ 1 + ! iotas go 0 to n-1
    dup [ 7 mod 0 = ] [ 10 >base 55 swap in? ] bi or
    [ 1 get -1 * 1 set ] when
    over 2 get swap nth push
    2 get 1 get + 2 set
  ] each ;
```

which is not good factor code, but a lot more clear (yes, I'm using numbers as variable names there, don't look at me like that!).

Comment: "Do I get a cookie?" Yes, you do.

Comment: Wow, that was unexpected! Ty, @LeakyNun :D

Comment: Wow, I love this! Curse you for using numbers as identifiers!

Comment: @cat i actually like it in a perverse way :P But locals solve the length issue of `SYMBOL:` a lot better: one letter names, and getting rid of `set` and `get`!

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6) 100

Returning result as a string array, no separators

```js
(m,n)=>(d=>{for(r=[],p=i=0;i++<m;d=i%7&&!~(i+'').search(7)?d:n-d,p=(p+d)%n)r[p]=(r[p]||'')+i})(1)||r
```

Or more readable, for 3 bytes more, returning result as an array of arrays

```js
(m,n)=>(d=>{for(r=[],p=i=0;i++<m;d=i%7&&!~(i+'').search(7)?d:n-d,p=(p+d)%n)r[p]=[...r[p]||[],i]})(1)||r
```

**Test** Using the new wonderful console feature of the Stack Snippets

```js
S=(m,n)=>(d=>{for(r=[],p=i=0;i++<m;d=i%7&&!~(i+'').search(7)?d:n-d,p=(p+d)%n)r[p]=(r[p]||'')+i})(1)||r

A=(m,n)=>(d=>{for(r=[],p=i=0;i++<m;d=i%7&&!~(i+'').search(7)?d:n-d,p=(p+d)%n)r[p]=[...r[p]||[],i]})(1)||r

console.log(S(42,5))
console.log(A(20,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

## J, <s>63</s> <s>60</s> <s>59</s> <s>58</s> 56 bytes

```
4 :'>:@I.(i.y)=/y|+/\0,_1^+/\(7 e."1 q:,.10#.inv])}.i.x'
```

#### Verification

```
   f =: 4 :'>:@I.(i.y)=/y|+/\0,_1^+/\(7 e."1 q:,.10#.inv])}.i.x'
   30 f 5
1  6  8 13 15 19 23 30
2  7 12 16 18 24  0  0
3 11 17 25  0  0  0  0
4 10 21 26 28  0  0  0
5  9 14 20 22 27 29  0
   42 f 5
1  6  8 13 15 19 23 30 35 39
2  7 12 16 18 24 31 40  0  0
3 11 17 25 32 41  0  0  0  0
4 10 21 26 28 33 37 42  0  0
5  9 14 20 22 27 29 34 36 38
   20 f 3
1 4 7 10 13 15 19
2 5 9 12 16 18  0
3 6 8 11 14 17 20
   14 f 10
 1 13
 2 12
 3 11
 4 10
 5  9
 6  8
 7  0
 0  0
 0  0
14  0
```