# Sequence Without Sevens

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, counting

This challenge is based on a drinking game. I advise against alcohol consumption while programming.

In this game, the players count up in turns: the first player says `1`, the second says `2` and so on. Here's the twist however: each number that **is divisible by 7 or has a 7 in its digits** (in base 10) is replaced by another counter. This means `7` is replaced by `1`, `14` is replaced by `2`, `17` is replaced by `3` and so on. For this "sub-sequence", the same rules apply! `35` would be replaced by `7`, which in turn is replaced by `1`. This process repeats until the number is "valid".

Here's a visualization of the first 100 numbers in the sequence:

```
n = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
gets replaced by:
                1                  2        3           4                 5  6                    7     8              9             10    11                   12 13                14          15       16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25             26       27          28                29 30       
gets replaced by:
                                                                                                  1                                                                                   2                       3           4                                   5           6                            

final sequence:
    1 2 3 4 5 6 1 8 9 10 11 12 13  2 15 16  3 18 19 20  4 22 23 24 25 26  5  6 29 30 31 32 33 34  1 36  8 38 39 40 41  9 43 44 45 46 10 48 11 50 51 52 53 54 55 12 13 58 59 60 61 62  2 64 65 66 15 68 69 16  3 18 19 20  4 22 23 24 25 80 81 82 83 26 85 86  5 88 89 90  6 92 93 94 95 96 29 30 99 100
```

In the final sequence, no number has a seven in its digits or is divisible by seven.

### Input description

- An integer `n` (`1 <= n <= 7777` or `0 <= n <= 7776`)

You may choose whether you use a 0-indexed or 1-indexed input.

### Output description

- The `n`th number in the sequence

### Examples

The examples are 1-indexed. For 0-indexed, subtract one from `n`.

```
n   ->   f(n)
1        1
5        5
7        1
35       1
77       23
119      1
278      86
2254     822
2255     2255
7777     3403
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: Hmm, is test case `278` correct? I get the correct result for each of them, but `278` becomes `86` instead of `5`. :S

Comment: @KevinCruijssen You're right, `278` is supposed to be `86`. `279` becomes `5`. Fixed!

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/65924/58563) but quite different.

Comment: I would swear this is a dupe but can't seem to find any.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Actually, I'm sure I've seen this before as well -- not just the one I already mentioned -- but couldn't find it either ...

Comment: @Arnauld Maybe it was deleted or something then. I remember it having something like `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, *1*, 8, 9, ..., 34, ***1***, 36, ...` (where stars are what it looked like in markdown)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Ah! [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/101231/cantors-unspeakable-numbers), I think (using Google rather than the internal search).

Comment: @Arnauld Yep that's an exact dupe...or not? That one asks you to print indefinitely, this one asks you for a specific item...it's somewhat like the "count up forever" question vs. my "count up folks!" question. Very different approaches.

Comment: I think it's similar enough to be a duplicate. We don't need both a "print at least `n` terms" and a "print the `n`th term" of every sequence challenge.

Answer (score 7):

## Java, <s>122</s> <s>121</s> <s>98</s> 97 bytes

```java
int c(int n){int a=0,b=0,c=n;for(;n-->0;c+=a=((--b+"").indexOf(55)&b%7)>>31);return a<0?-b:c(c);}
```

-23 bytes thanks to *@Nevay*.
-1 byte thanks to *@Neil*.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hU7BasMwDL33K0ShQ6Z1SNqGbPOSfcHYocexg@24w12ihMTpNkK@PXMKu84C6SHe09O7yKvkTWvoUn7OupJ9Dy/S0jhbcqBxmcTGBWQe75RvnZM4Nx0K4ryIhd7mMkfkXG3XaxZZKs336xnTlN2pTcaK4pAw0Rk3dATyKX7m6lGjZmKaAdpBVVZD76TzcG1sCbV/jifXWfp4ewfJxhX4WiJBDTmQ@botyMSNOP30ztRRM7io9TeuIqwjjQn7n08DfBbgD0GDkEOSPAQU@@w@pNinx7AkHPUv7LSa5l8)

```java
int c(int n){                            // Method with integer as parameter and return-type
  int a=0,                               //  Flag integer
      b=0,                               //  Regular counter
      c=n;                               //  7-counter
  for(;n-->0;                            //  Loop over the input
    c+=                                  //   Append `c` with:
       a=                                //    Set `a` to:
         ((--b+"").indexOf(55)&b&7)      //     If `b` is divisible by or contains 7:
                                         //     (and decrease `b` by 1 in the process)
                                   >>31  //      Bitwise right shift so `a` is either `-1` or `0`
  );                                     //  End of loop
  return a<0?                            //  If `a` is now -1:
    -b                                   //   Return the regular counter `b` (as positive)
   :                                     //  Else:
    c(c);                                //   Recursive call with 7-counter `c` as input
}                                        // End of method
```

Comment: 102, I think: `int c(int n){int q=0,r=1,a=1,b=0;for(;--n>0;b+=q=(++a+"").contains("7")|a%7<1?1:0);return q>0?c(b):a;}`

Comment: 101 bytes:
 [`int c(int n){int r=1,a=1,b=1;for(;n-->0;r=(a+"").contains("7")|a++%7<1?b++:a-1);return--a==r?r:c(r);}`](https://tio.run/##hU7LasMwELznKxZDQUKxqdIGp1GVfEFPOZYe1ooTlNiSkeSE4vrbXTnQa7WwOyzzYC54w9x2tbkcr5Nq0Hv4QG2GSZsAiszX0GEGJ/kS41aSi5N1RJg83z0LJwmyLKOFsiZEpydZmdEfZOypfOf7irEt5pwKV4feRQtK6fZuq4ijYpwAur5qtAIfMES4WX2ENsaQQ3DanD@/AOmwgDhzLWhBgqnvj4dQ8SAO3z7UbWH7UHTRExpD2kIRTv/n1wm@TPAvyYBUAudvCcWq3KQUq/VrWpKu@ld2XIzTLw)

Comment: 98 bytes: `int c(int n){int r=1,a=0,b=1;for(;n-->0;r=((--a+"").indexOf(55)&a%7)<0?a:b++);return a<r?c(r):-r;}`

Comment: Actually my answer is only 98 bytes, once you remove the unused `r=1,`...

Comment: 97 bytes: [`int c(int n){int q=0,a=0,b=n;while(n-->0)b+=q=((--a+"").indexOf(55)&a%7)>>31;return q<0?-a:c(b);}`](https://tio.run/##hY7PToNAEIfvfYpJE81O6hJoJagIfQLjoUfTw7CsupUO/5ZWQ3h2pGk8ukwyM4dvfpnvQCeSZaX5kH@NqqC2hRcy3LeWrFGjYQtKXCZjf1l14t/R1FnC8fnTFFqwlKmP2SqpEyGkpNVyiZ7hXH@/voswxFu6iTBNN0HcaNs1DPWzv5X0pESG8TACVF1WGAXXj3AqTQ7HSUHsbGP4420PhP0Cptr9tFYfvbKzXjUhW7BQIkCM/6ehk0ZOupkJu9NB8Ojk6@jBzdfh/dzBnOCf4rAYxl8 "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 77 bytes

```python
g=lambda a:a%7<1or'7'in str(a)
f=lambda a:g(a)and f(sum(map(g,range(a))))or a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYwxDsIwDEX3niILqiOxpKUKIHoYo5JQiTiRGwZOn4YB4Xh6z0/66ZOfkcZS/PzCcF9Q4RUP9mYi97ZfSW2ZAXXn/tlXR1qUg@0dIGACf2Qk/6j/epEVlsQrZXBgtO5@PAm2gscmyGLMRdhgz9KG6dRqO/MdKjs)

Comment: Does this not work in Python 2? Then you could do `'7'in\`a\`` instead of `'7'in str(a)`

Comment: @Ruud Leaky doesn't like Python 2.

Comment: Shouldn't this be 23 bytes?!

Comment: @Shaggy Huh? Why?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer (took me 2 hours to figure it out) because `f(77) = 23`

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>72</s> 69 bytes

```js
f=
n=>[...a=Array(n)].reduce(_=>a[++i]=i%7>7*/7/.test(i)?i:a[++j],i=j=0)
```

```html
<input type=number min=1 oninput=o.textContent=f(+this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Edit: Saved 3 bytes thanks to @Shaggy.

Comment: 69 bytes: `n=>[...a=Array(n)].reduce(_=>a[++i]=i%7>7*/7/.test(i)?i:a[++j],i=j=0)`

Comment: @Shaggy I can't believe I forgot to use `reduce`... _hangs head in shame_

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>79</s> 75 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy)*

```
f=a=>(z=a=>a%7<1|/7/.test(a))(a)?f([...Array(a)].reduce(a=>a+z(b++),b=0)):a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7LDoIwEEX3fkU3hjZgsSipr2L8DmQxQDEQbElBE4n/XimymHPvTc5iGnhDX5i6GzZKl9LaSoBI8OgIa35h35CHdJD9gIGQ6a4VTimlN2PgM82MGlm@Comd7484930S5GJLyAlsoVWvW0lb/cDpCiEWTIgduMPuX@fO2NFFxA9zRPF@ycVxVkaf0GFAIkGV@4Y2ulbYuyuPkLP9AQ)

Comment: Just finished golfing mine down ... and then spotted you beat me to the identical solution. :\

Comment: 75 bytes: `f=a=>(z=a=>a%7<1|/7/.test(a))(a)?f([...Array(a)].reduce(a=>a+z(b++),b=0)):a`

Comment: @Shaggy. I actually had tried using reduce, but before I rearranged variables, so it had turned out that it was longer. I forgot to recheck it again. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 65 bytes

```
f a{f#[seq(1,a)|[1]if g _]if g a else[a]}g a{[a%7<1 or"7"in`$a`]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYnRCsIgGEav21N8rAIFb1wNC3oTke2HNISay3XnfHazdXPOx/liuFMpDpTcXi/2zaQgvmppvMMDw18E@1ysJpPrTpqO6iYRYqtaP40HGk0uL/ITUrNzzHO4EOFRg5YCvYASOP1ULeVVoFOXiq4/b9wepQxWzNFPHzbwJpcv)

A port of Leaky Nun's [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140172/66323).

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>26</s> 23 bytes

```
LÐ7Ösε7å}~_*[¤0Ê#D_O£]¤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P8wNWFiMWX//0zDkDfDlnPOtTfDpX1@XypbwqQww4ojRF9PwqNdwqT//zM1)

**Explanation**

```
L                         # push range [1 ... n]
 Ð                        # triplicate
  7Ö                      # check if number in one copy for equality to 0 after mod by 7
    sε7å}                 # check each number in one copy if they contain 7
         ~_               # OR these 2 lists and invert
           *              # multiply with the range, 
                          # giving a list with 0s where the numbers need to be replaced
            [¤0Ê#    ]    # loop until the last number in the list is not 0
                 D        # duplicate the list
                  _       # invert it, 
                          # giving a list with 1s for the numbers that need to be replaced
                   O      # sum
                    £     # take these many elements from the list
                      ¤   # RESULT: push the last element of the list
```

**Previous 26 byte solutions**

```
>GNN7ÖN7å~Dˆ[_#¯s£OÐ7Ös7å~ 
>G1UN[Ð7Ös7å~XiDˆ}_#¯s£O0U
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>104</s> <s>98</s> 95 bytes

*-6 bytes by getting rid of sprintf+index and looking manually for a 7 in an integer's digits*
*-3 bytes using the deprecated POSIX bzero instead of memset*

A function writing the result in the global variable `r`. Usage: `l(<int>)`

Result is 1-indexed.

```c
r,o[9];b(i,s){for(r=s=++o[i];s&&s%10^7;s/=10);r%7&&!s?:b(i+1);}l(f){for(bzero(o,36);f--;b(0));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc7fCoIwFMfxe59iCcqGk5xmZkN6EDPIP4uBuTizLhKf3UbdNq8/53v4NeGtaZYFqCrzitdYUk0moQBDoYsgUKWsuPZ97bHoknG9LVhEOHiZ72/06WjuA0b43GPxq@p3BwormuwJF2FoHkbE@CKHEd2vcsAvJVuCJgehHjNCH2BEYNdrz4NLgfAvpDbIbJDYE2vDWG6jODtYKU53K7ay4/8Sg9CNTxhQxJ3ZWT4)

Explanation:

```c
/*
  r = value of the nth element
  o = array of counters (o[0] == main counter)
 */
r,o[9];

// Recursive function, "i" is the counter index 
// "s" is used to determine if an int contain a 7 digit
b(i,s){
  /*
    1. Increases the value of the counter
    2. Stores the result into r and s
    3. Divide s by 10 until it is equal to 0 or its remainder is 7
   */ 
  for(r=s=++o[i];s&&s%10^7;s/=10);

  /*
    if:
      r%7 (r modulo 7) AND it contains no 7 digit
    then:
      nothing
    else:
      calls b with the next counter index
   */
  r%7&&!s?:b(i+1);
}

// Main function: initializes counters and plays
// the sequence until the nth member is calculated
l(f){
  for(bzero(o,36);f--;b(0));
}
```

Comment: Finally, this is not the longest solution anymore. Sorry, Java.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 57 bytes

```
Last[i=1;If[DigitCount[#,10,7]>0||7∣#,i++,#]&~Array~#]&
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 36 bytes

```
L?!hbbhx.f|/`Z`7!%Z7b)b;WnyyQyQ=yQ;Q
```

Fixed completely, but is now an unholy mess of letters and can certainly be golfed quite a bit.

1-indexed

Comment: Fixed, I put the h in front of the Q instead of G /)_-

Comment: It should work now...

Comment: I missed copy-pasting the leading L to define the lambda

Comment: Nice work! Looks good now!

Comment: Thanks! Still needs some work though...

Answer (score 1):

### J, 52 bytes

```
i=:('7'&e.@":+.0=7&|)"0
f=:]`(#@}.@I.@:i@i.@>:)@.i^:_
```

Result is 1-indexed. Using it is pretty straightforward:

```
f 7777
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P9PWSkPdXF0tVc9ByUpbz8DWXK1GU8mAK83WKjZBQ9mhVs/BU8/BKtMhU8/BzkrTQS8zziqeKzU5I18hTcEcCP7//w8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 52 + 1 (-p) = 53 bytes

```perl
map{$s=0;do{$\=++$c[$s++]}until$\!~/7/&&$\%7}1..$_}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83saBapdjWwDolv1olxlZbWyU5WqVYWzu2tjSvJDNHJUaxTt9cX01NJUbVvNZQT08lvrb6/39z83/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA3@6xYAAA)

**How?**

`@c` is an array of counters.  `$c[0]` holds the main counter that determines which element we're working on.  Each successive element holds another counter that is only accessed when the previous one contains a 7 or is divisible by 7.

```perl
map              # Loop to find the appropriate element
  $s=0;          # reset index of counters
  do{            # looping through the counters
    $\=++c[$s++] # increment the counter and the index; $\ is our output variable
  }until         # don't quit until
       $\!~/7/   # the result has no 7s
       &&$\%7    # and is indivisble by 7
}1..$_           # do this until the input is reached
}{  # close the implicit loop created by the -p flag and force output of $\
```

<s># [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 64 + 1 (-p) = 65 bytes</s>

```perl
while($c[0]<$_){$s=0;do{$\=++$c[$s++]}while($\=~/7/||$\%7==0)}}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/788IzMnVUMlOdog1kYlXrNapdjWwDolv1olxlZbGyisUqytHVsLVRVjW6dvrl9ToxKjam5ra6BZW1v9/7@x6b/8gpLM/Lzi/7q@pnoGhgb/dQsA)