# Solve Hitori Puzzles

Tags: code-golf, game

## Introduction

Write a solver for the [Hitori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitori) puzzles using least bytes.

## Challenge

Your task is write a solver for the Hitori (ひとり, the word for "alone" in Japanese; the meaning of the game name is "Leave me alone") logical puzzles. The rules are as follows:

- You are presented with a n-by-n grid of cells, each cell contains an integer between 1 and n (inclusive).
- Your goal is to make sure that no number appear more than once in each row and each column of the grid, by removing numbers from the given grid, subject to the restriction indicated in the next two rules,
- You cannot remove two numbers from two adjacent (horizontally or vertically) cells.
- The remaining numbered cells must be all connected to each other. It means that any two remaining numbered cells can be connected with a curve that is composed solely of segments connecting adjacent remaining numbers (horizonally or vertically). (Thanks to @user202729 for pointing out that this is missing)

I hope the rules are clear by now. If there is anything unclear about the rules, check the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitori).

## Test Cases

The cells from which the numbers are removed are represented with 0s.

```
Input  ->  Output

4
2 2 2 4      0 2 0 4
1 4 2 3  ->  1 4 2 3
2 3 2 1      2 3 0 1
3 4 1 2      3 0 1 2

4
4 2 4 3      0 2 4 3
4 1 1 2  ->  4 1 0 2
3 1 2 1      3 0 2 1
4 3 1 3      0 3 1 0

5
1 5 3 1 2      1 5 3 0 2
5 4 1 3 4      5 0 1 3 4
3 4 3 1 5  ->  3 4 0 1 5
4 4 2 3 3      4 0 2 0 3
2 1 5 4 4      2 1 5 4 0

8
4 8 1 6 3 2 5 7      0 8 0 6 3 2 0 7
3 6 7 2 1 6 5 4      3 6 7 2 1 0 5 4
2 3 4 8 2 8 6 1      0 3 4 0 2 8 6 1
4 1 6 5 7 7 3 5  ->  4 1 0 5 7 0 3 0
7 2 3 1 8 5 1 2      7 0 3 0 8 5 1 2
3 5 6 7 3 1 8 4      0 5 6 7 0 1 8 0
6 4 2 3 5 4 7 8      6 0 2 3 5 4 7 8
8 7 1 4 2 3 5 6      8 7 1 4 0 3 0 6

9
8 6 5 6 8 1 2 2 9      8 0 5 6 0 1 2 0 9
5 6 2 4 1 7 9 8 3      5 6 2 4 1 7 9 8 3
5 8 2 5 9 9 8 2 6      0 8 0 5 0 9 0 2 0
9 5 6 6 4 3 8 4 1      9 5 6 0 4 3 8 0 1
1 1 6 3 9 9 5 6 2  ->  0 1 0 3 9 0 5 6 2
1 1 4 7 3 8 3 8 6      1 0 4 7 0 8 3 0 6
3 7 4 1 2 6 4 5 5      3 7 0 1 2 6 4 5 0
3 3 1 9 8 7 7 4 5      0 3 1 9 8 0 7 4 5
2 9 7 5 3 5 9 1 3      2 9 7 0 3 5 0 1 0
```

These test cases are taken from [Concept Is Puzzles](http://www.conceptispuzzles.com/index.aspx?uri=puzzle/euid/010000009ca896ef2fb6a5a4b63d1dd96e51c0295f72a24561f98409baf064ecfb79f6bba827f62665d86d96d267ca4f6bc6bf07/play), [PuzzleBooks](http://www.puzzlebooks.net/images/puzzles/solutions/070871f80140c9de6463dcb95c66c8a4.png), [Concept Is Puzzles](http://www.conceptispuzzles.com/index.aspx?uri=puzzle/hitori/rules), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitori), and [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iaAdKqT2TVo), respectively.

## Specs

- No need to worry about exception handling.
- You **can** assume that the input is always a valid puzzle with a **unique** solution and you can take advantage of this in writing your code.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the lowest number of bytes wins.
- 4 <= n <= 9 (16 originally, changed to 9 following Stewie Griffin's suggestion, also save some trouble in IO)
- You can take input and provide output through [any standard form](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods), and you are free to choose the format.
- Some suggestions for the output format are (but you are not restricted to these)

  - Outputting the final grid
  - Outputting the grid containing all removed numbers
  - Output a list of coordinates of one of the above
- As usual, [default loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply here.

---

<sub>Related(inspired by this challenge): [Check if All Elements In a Matrix Are Connected](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/154363/check-if-all-elements-in-a-matrix-are-connected)</sub>

<sub>My last challenge: [Extension of the Game of Sevens](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/154147/extension-of-the-game-of-sevens)</sub>

Comment: I suggest that you require deterministic runtime, or require that the largest test case can be solved in no more than 1 minute (or maybe more/less). Also, you say `4 <= n <= 16`, but the largest test case is for `n=9`. I suggest you either post a `n=16` test case, or say `4 <= n <= 9`. Nice challenge by the way :)

Comment: @StewieGriffin how about just having a separate fastest algorithm challenge?

Comment: @StewieGriffin Tried to add a 16x16 but not yet quite ready. Changed to 9 now.

Comment: @JonathanAllan As you wish.

Comment: Re "I decide to make a change to see whether it would be better": It would definitely be worse. Also you should not change an already posted challenge.

Comment: (I rolled back the challenge. If you want, you can post a separate fastest algorithm challenge. Don't worry, we allow the same challenge with different winning criteria)

Comment: @JonathanAllan (Just FYI, I posted a Jelly solution to the connectivity challenge)

Comment: @user202729 I didn't see your message until now. Thank you. I still don't have a good grasp of the types of puzzles ...

Comment: Hitori = 一人 = Singleplayer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 374 bytes

```hs
import Data.Array;import Data.List;r=range;p=partition
c(e,f)=p(\(b,p)->any(==1)[(b-d)^2+(p-q)^2|(d,q)<-e])f
n#g=[s|(o,(e:f))<-[p((==0).(g!))$indices g],
 null.fst$c(o,o),null.snd$until(null.fst)c([e],f),
 s<-case[((l,c),d)|((l,c),h)<-assocs g,h>0,
 d<-[filter((==h).(g!))$r((l,c+1),(l,n))++r((l+1,c),(n,c))],d/=[]]
 of[]->[g];((c,d):_)->n#(g//[(c,0)])++n#(g//[(c,0)|c<-d])]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHbbtswDH33V3hIHkiETmLn4jiJAwzYy4D9gaYVrm8R6squ5DwUyL9nlJIWBTYQpMTDc0haPhf2pe662029Dr0Zwx/FWMy/G1O8H74iv5QdDyY3hW7rw5APhRnVqHodlFBTg/kAv@GZBoxOhX6HPI9RwHNU4Z9kBkP0xucVKnrDY1RLbAI9aXNhr9AT1PsGGRYDsGyJc2i/IU6VrlRZ27CVFIT60nXzxo7TkgU9ks@trqYXPaoOPspYgqglb8MSe4zKwtYCoKMSqcLr43bmWYW1fcm96XxaMrfi6Y3qxtq4Fc4fKxivmMVIfGrE2cwhs9h1Ac0RJVWLXEgZhH0jZHQSrTwAlDxt/8QvoSfQLhaCgSVKln/Nr@UxqiTKWxSFMMH9/qceo5N/dwC@EzuiB8V/UBm8Fkrng1F6nGql66DpLyZfTzr@Tw9@TG71Na0RRULO1hSzJ7R6eMzRYYkMXI88@1eeUcbyHW1pw75zZLbMZ/eGKWc7brThmHDMfJ5w/c7aMmvFiOM623KWfXaI/UqpZzh31fS@lFdu2FZsse@a@trGb5D6ipvHnyFvfwE)

Comment: Thank you. Very impressive. Personally I am a beginner but also a big fan of Haskell.

Comment: https://tio.run/##bVHbbtswDH33V2RIHkiYTmLn4jiJAwzYy4D9gaYVrm8R6squrDwUyL9nlJIWBTYQpMTDw0NaPhfjS911t5t6HXpjJz8KW8y/G1O8H74iv9RoDyY3hW7rw5APhbHKql4HJdTUYD7Ab3imAaNTod8hz2MU8BxV@CcJYYje@LxCRW94jGqJTaCnbS7GK/QE9b5BhsUA3LbEObTfEGdKV6qsx0krSV@6bt6MdlYyvcd7PupqdtFWdfBRxhJELXkXGo9RWYy1AOioRKrw@rideU4xjn3JunQ@LaniuY3qbG3c8PPHcOP5YYzEp0YMQ4eEsdMAzRElVYtcSNk3QkYn0coDQMmT9k/8AnoK7WIhGFii5Oav@bU8RpVEeYuiCUxxv/@pbXTy7w3Ad2JH9KD4DyqD10LpfDBK25lWug6a/mLy9bTj//Pgx@QWX9MaUSTkbE0xe0Krh8ccHZbIwGnk2b/tGWXcvqMtbdh3jsyW@ewumHK2Y6ENx4Rj5vOE63fWllkrRhzX2Zaz7FMh9iulnuHcVdP7Ur5zw7Zii71q6msbv0HqK24ef4a8/QU

Comment: The above was too many characters too leave a comment alongside. It is just removing some whitespace

Comment: https://tio.run/##bVHbbtswDH33V2RIHkiESmvn6jQKNmAvA/YHmja4tuwoc2THdoGuS789o5RuGLCBIGUeHh5S8iHrv5u6vl7tqW26YfQxG7LZh67LfkR/I59tP0Sd7DJXmaiVbdYNdrCNi87SPdX1rOTyEQyVKFv4Ao/Uotg3nYJHUeDXZAqtOPMpZXyBgs64E0ZjGblxJVV/qc0ADZlt6IZdjDOo3iFOrCtsbvpRRefJkRkNUpjWu2Ly5AZbj86jIyijeS71O5FnvVHwQgVe4OU91JQjHXhW1vdN7mUO@3sqdkKVth5MByDl4fcszpg/jZH4dIjTqUemsdcAxxE1FXuldVNCzhO238S@aH6eWE3lXNIPbgzV3Z2CZ7rHy/NOnDS@PjBLVVpfhRjBGLfbT24Q@/C@APxN7IgBVP9BdXTKrJNtZ90wcdaZqGyeOrkY1/w/3vgx@Z0XtEBUCXlbUMye0PzNY44eS3TkNWT6b3tKKbdvaEVL9o0ns6UhuwmuOduw0JJjwjENecL1G2vFrDkjnuttxVn6RyEOK60Dw7uvrm9Lhc4l25wtDqrrUFuGDdah4ufxNfT1Fw

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 133 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
{q←{⊢/4 2⍴⍵}⌺3 3⋄g←⍵=⊂∪,⍵⋄⍵×~1⊃{((⌈/q b)⌈b<{2<≢∪0,,(⍵×⊢⌈⌈/∘q)⍣≡⍵×(⍴⍵)⍴1+⍳≢,⍵}¨~b∘⌈¨⊂⍤2∘.≡⍨⍳⍴b)(+/↑w<g×⌈.⌈⍨w×g)⌈w b←⍵}⍣≡×\(⌈/=∘⌽⍨q⍵)0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVDNbhMxEL7zFHvbDQ3JeOyxvSh9Ey6JaKKKKCFRpQhF2wOgKg3ZCg4oHCHlEHElXJC4NG/iFwmfvZUq7/pn5vuz@2/HL16/64@no1O4@3o5DTef6TTEvJzFKax3XZNxqA@h/lOFzV@d6fDp4wg9FM7D@n1Y/WpjiyLm4/ZahfWHZVGEzao7ywYtrIPeknvhdgcktdtFgkEXnQgKq2@zVqjvw@2P1CkaL5QO6izUv0GM@tXD/noALCgP@2hb/2QcO4m2j7j6MGgVZ91w82XRG8Fhs@pEi3q/OG5HMcciGzSxq8buuH2VYp4n2X9AzqIxVafTVbz7BFNHnqPeEejhAuma/ewiyjxGWO84m2STFPoOyRLkAuA5QMOs/zIf9i/HOUjZvED9@7wFQD59k1fPrnJmNsqwxlDaKCamxzMpfJwDY9igpVgrVkajnM4ECCvSiiJGCbpioIGhxEACiljRIBZKDUIBBqmRWMYrq1mcto6VFZCMZ2@VwcE5LQ6eXuAs1mFnLBBinPcuZhRLnsCnhk8QhUfDJ3GkKf6RT@CTApie@GjZmMFbsV4xl2LxFK70WjxLWXq2KFmjPe6OmGUEKGWc9tpb7fBY1ohorUrvnBEunWgplfZww8vRkyBiCpWUSgRBUhi6pChIxhEQEKQkSBQFqREkjZej/D8)

My implementation of rule #4 (cells must form a single connected component) is rather wasteful, but still this passes all tests in about 10 seconds on TIO.

---

The overall algorithm: Store two boolean matrices `b` and `w` for cells that are certain to be black and white respectively. Initialise `b` as all-zero. Initialise `w` as 1 only for those cells that have opposite matching neighbours.

Repeat until `b` and `w` settle down:

- add to `b` cells that are on the same line (horizontal or vertical) and of the same value as a cell in `w`
- add to `w` the immediate neighbours of all cells in `b`
- add to `w` all cutpoints - cells whose removal would split the graph of non-black cells into multiple connected components

Finally, output `not(b)` multiplied by the original matrix.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest and explanation. I think what you described is also a typical algorithm used if one is to solve the puzzle by hand.

Comment: To be honest, I never even tried to solve Hitori by hand. I got these tricks [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitori#Solving_techniques) and I don't have a proof that the algorithm would always converge all the way to the (unique) solution.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 62 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

Uses [user202729's isConnected monadic link](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154447/53748) from another question.

---

```
FJṁa@µ«Ḋoµ€ZUµ4¡ÐLFQL<3
ḟ0ĠḊ€
¬T€œ&2\;Ç€FȦ
ZÇȯÇ_1Ŀ
2ḶṗLṗLa⁸ÇÞḢ
```

A full program printing a representation of a list of lists.
Works by brute force and is stupidly inefficient.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/N6@HOxkSHQ1sPrX64oyv/0NZHTWuiQg9tNTm08PAEH7dAHxtjroc75hscWQCUBspxHVoTAqSOTlYzirE@3A5kup1YxhV1uP3E@sPt8YZH9nMZPdyx7eHO6T4gnPioccfh9sPzHu5Y9P///@hoQx0FIyCK1VGINgIzjUFMYx0FkERsLAA)** - a 3 by 3, since it is too inefficient to run even a size 4 within the 60 second TIO limit!

#### How?

```
FJṁa@µ«Ḋoµ€ZUµ4¡ÐLFQL<3 - Link 1 isConnected? List of lists
...                     - 1 if connected 0 if not -- see linked answer in the header

ḟ0ĠḊ€ - Link 2, helperFor-AnyRepeatedValues: list
ḟ0    - filter out zeros
  Ġ   - group indices by value (i.e. [[indices of min],...,[indices of max]]
   Ḋ€ - dequeue €ach -- leaving a list of empty lists iff no repeated values
      -                 any remaining values are non-zero (1-based indexing in Jelly)

¬T€œ&2\;Ç€FȦ - Link 3, columnwiseAnyAdjacentZerosOrRowwiseAnyRepeatedValues: list of lists
¬            - logical not (convert all zeros to ones and all others to zeros)
 T€          - for €ach row get a list of truthy indexes (i.e. indexes of original zeros)
     2\      - pairwise reduction (i.e. for neighbouring rows) with:
   œ&        -   intersection (empty if no columnwise adjacent original zeros
             -                 any remaining values are non-zero due to 1-based indexing)
        Ç€   - call last link (1) as a monad for €ach row
       ;     - concatenate
          F  - flatten into a single list (empty iff no columnwise adjacent original zeros
             -                                   AND no rowwise repeated values)
           Ȧ - any and all (0 if empty [or contains any zero -- never] else 1)

ZÇȯÇ_1Ŀ - Link 4, validity check? list of lists
Z       - transpose
 Ç      - call last link (2) as a monad rowwiseAnyAdjacentZerosOrColumnwiseAnyRepeatedValues?
   Ç    - call last link (2) as a monad columnwiseAnyAdjacentZerosOrRowwiseAnyRepeatedValues?
  ȯ     - logical OR
     1Ŀ - call link 1 as a monad (isConnected?)
    _   - subtract
        - this yields -1 for valid, while it yields 0 or 1 if not.

2ḶṗLṗLa⁸ÇÞḢ - Main link: list of lists
2Ḷ          - lowered range of 2 -> [0,1]
   L        - length (number of rows in the input)
  ṗ         - Cartesian power (all lists of zeros and ones of length L)
     L      - length (number of rows in the input again)
    ṗ       - Cartesian power (all grids of zeros and ones of same shape as the input)
       ⁸    - the input
      a     - logical AND -- effectively uses each of the formed grids as a mask
         Þ  - sort by:
        Ç   -   last link (3) as a monad
          Ḣ - head
            - implicit print
```

Comment: NIce as a start. Thank you. I will take a look.

Comment: You forgot the 4th rule. (connected)

Comment: (good luck with implementing BFS/DFS/DSU in Jelly)

Comment: Oh... will delete when at a computer. Thanks.

Comment: yeah, I don't think this is possible in, say, <60 bytes of Jelly, not to say <100...

Answer (score 1):

## Python3, 567 bytes:

```py
E=enumerate
M=[(0,1),(0,-1),(1,0),(-1,0)]
V=lambda b:[(x,r,y,v)for x,r in E(b)for y,v in E(r)]
J=list.count
def C(b,x,y,s):
 b=eval(str(b));b[x][y]=0
 if b in s:return
 t=[(x,y)for x,_,y,v in V(b)if v]
 q=[t.pop()]
 while q:
  x,y=q.pop(0)
  for X,Y in M:
   if(N:=(x+X,y+Y))in t:q+=[N];t.remove(N)
 if[]==t:return b
def f(b):
 q,s=[b],[]
 while q:
  b=q.pop(0)    
  F=1
  for x,r,y,v in V(b):
   if v and(J(r,v)>1 or J([*[*zip(*b)][y]],v)>1):
    F=0
    if all(b[x+X][y+Y]for X,Y in M if 0<=x+X<len(b)and 0<=y+Y<len(r))and(B:=C(b,x,y,s)):q+=[B];s+=[B]
  if F:return b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHBbuIwED3XXzE3bHBRQkBahbqHrtoDUjlWIG9UxcVRI4UkOIYl@/PsjMmyu1IVyeN589688aTt/WdTJ99ad7k8K1sf99bl3rJXpXkkYyHxvKcQywjPewoZe1NVvje7HEyq@Vk62cuTKBoHeIeyhmduQorwNXUoWqmq7Pz0oznWnu1sAd@5kWeUdiJlYJQ95RXvvEOtWBp9znSfqYhBWYChLl3qrD@6moFX5NoPju9ysHlDJZJPGYOD0n7aNi1HX/j5WVYWDmiC7F4dQiESmFKDjdyS@JXK6MXXqeLnyUb2k60QWPDpYaL0Olv6qbP75mT5WtBQOlPKDyOBCQ8qcABsc5Cd0iaT@n9vc3O@w@xFxcMAw/7@vGCYA06Q1zu@4g5X@xgDEldcj/X4V9nysRG0nSyUrgpsGIWI0ryqOC5wskHSZJv9@0oqRw8Kaw@VrdEOTQhAXgCcIIQ/perv3xFhA0/ZsguBBY@X29MvXQwKRqMRmwF9cxbDHGOCeYIxZgnmMcwYcbrZQCbKHElUomJCJ5IRw1tyJScDOYZFgGdsEXphx9CVsAVKgl9wJCbmQU7/xDfvpsndjmPETd0NU2s93uctL2svoZx2bVV6LkRYVUmLKsrKW8fXTW0loHSgjH7UI6Qx1jqU8oLf2nexEOILePY1nCB8@Q0)

Comment: [Handful of relatively trivial golfs for 557](https://tio.run/##VZFLb8IwDMfv@RQ@JjSgVrtMBe8AQurEYRLiFkVTM4KoVPpIQ0f35ZnTda9LHMeP399OM/hzXT08Nu5@X6Otrhfrcm/ZC/JYJkLSOQ8mkTGd82DYBsv8Yo45mFTxm3RykL041Q7oDkUFa25Gl56/XCc0y7AsOr94q6@VZ0d7gmdu5I1KO5EyMGj7vOSdd1QrlkbdtBo0xgyKE5jQpUud9VdXMfAYqMNEfJUTZkOVlNxrBi0qv2jqhhMX3s9FaaElCGUP2I4BmgIgNDjILBS/hDCx@DZFfosOcogyISjg0zZCtdVLv3D2UveWb0UQpTSinySBGQc6kQBq08pZh8po@Q9t5P4HLZMJPu3uW/2kAXrIqyPPuKO1PiWUl3E1U7OPouEzI8Ji9Bj5Kgiq9ynGYpWXJafNRQdKiTL9d7zQNl4hxValrYhFhHmyorTRdyI88F2Kv78ixsl3etmNho3S9j8j3@@f) (footer elided for link space)